# Magento images lightbox not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento

Normally I have a lot to explain and a lot of snippets to copy and paste but this time the problem is pretty clear and the solution totally unclear for me.

The problem is that our customers webshop does not display the images in a lightbox anymore.
This appeared suddenly.

Anyone any ideas ?
The url, for example : http://www.software-discounter.nl/index.php/office-producten/http-www-software-discounter-nl-microsoft-html.html

http://www.software-discounter.nl

Comment: check js console. it's full of errors

Comment: Thanks, just seen it, I think it might be that Jquery is not loaded properly ?

Comment: it's not loaded at all

Comment: Weird indeed.. Going to check how Magento normally loads jquery because in the head sections I can not find anything (also for working Magento sites, not just this one)

Comment: Magento by default doesn't use jQuery. It uses PrototypeJS

Comment: Weird, the plugins seem to use Jquery.

Comment: Plugin may use it but it doesn't mean that jQuery itself is included in your project.

Comment: I'm reinstalling the theme right now, thanks for your input.